# Simultaneously uploading files to multiple ftp with php?

Tags: php

My application is uploading the same content to two storages. Firstly, application uploads files to the first ftp and then to another one. Is is possible to upload to both FTP simultaneously?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ftp_nb_fput`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-fput.php) and have a loop which calls [`ftp_nb_continue`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-continue.php) for both handlers, alternating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to open two connections for each site to upload files.