# How to connect ftp with multiple connections in php

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

How can I upload or download a file with multiple connection in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View [Simultaneously uploading files to multiple ftp with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408415/simultaneously-uploading-files-to-multiple-ftp-with-php) for answers.

Simply You can create multiple connection using multiple objects..

Comment: Suppose there are 1000 users simultaneously uploading files to the same FTP server with same FTP logins. Using PHP's ftp_put() method, will work correctly?